# React + Typescript + MUI type error - No overload matches this call on MUI icon import

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a component that imports:

```
import LogoutIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Logout";
import useLogout from "@/hooks/auth/useLogout";

const { trigger: logoutTrigger } = useLogout();
```

But where I use this component is here:

```
            <LogoutIcon
              type="button"
              onClick={logoutTrigger}
              sx={LogoutIconSx}
              cursor="pointer"
            />
```

And it all gets highlighted with the following error:

```
(property) onClick: <SWRData = any>(extraArgument?: null | undefined, options?: SWRMutationConfiguration<any, any, never, "/logout", SWRData> | undefined) => Promise<any>
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<SvgIconClasses> | undefined; color?: "inherit" | ... 8 more ... | undefined; ... 6 more ...; viewBox?: string | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...>): Element | null', gave the following error.
Property 'component' is missing in type '{ type: string; onClick: <SWRData = any>(extraArgument?: null | undefined, options?: SWRMutationConfiguration<any, any, never, "/logout", SWRData> | undefined) => Promise<...>; sx: SxProps<...>; cursor: string; }' but required in type '{ component: ElementType<any>; }'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">>): Element | null', gave the following error.
    Type '<SWRData = any>(extraArgument?: null | undefined, options?: SWRMutationConfiguration<any, any, never, "/logout", SWRData> | undefined) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<SVGSVGElement>'.
Types of parameters 'extraArgument' and 'event' are incompatible.
        Type 'MouseEvent<SVGSVGElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'null | undefined'.ts(2769)
OverridableComponent.d.ts(21, 7): 'component' is declared here.
index.d.ts(1484, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onClick' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<SvgIconClasses> | undefined; color?: "inherit" | "disabled" | ... 7 more ... | undefined; ... 6 more ...; viewBox?: string | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...>'
```

And here I have the hook:

```
const cookies = new Cookies();

const fetcher = (url: string) => axios.post(url).then((res) => res.data);

export default function useLogout() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const { trigger, error } = useSWRMutation("/logout", fetcher, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      cookies.remove(ACCESS_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME);
      router.push("/login");
    },
  });

  return {
    trigger,
    error,
  };
}
```

I've noticed that if I change `onClick={logoutTrigger}` to `onClick={() => console.log(test}` the problem disappears.

Also if I set as `any` `onClick={logoutTrigger as any}` the error disappears, but I want to avoid type casting.

P.s. I am using MUI v5

Why am I getting this error? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely issue is that onClick event handler is trying to pass event object as an argument into the `logoutTrigger` function which doesn't accept event object as an argument.

Please try the following code, it might help:

```
<LogoutIcon
  type="button"
  onClick={() => logoutTrigger()}
  sx={LogoutIconSx}
  cursor="pointer"
/>
```

Comment: Yes! That works. How can I understand it in future? How did you understand it from my description?

Comment: What popped out to me was the messages saying: No overload matches this call. basically what it meant is that the callback signature which is expected by onClick doesn't match the signature of callback that you are trying to pass in as an argument. here is example of how function signatures look like in typescript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions:~:text=type%20GreetFunction%20%3D%20(a%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B

Answer (score 1):

when `onClick` is invoked you are trying to pass its parameters into the `trigger` function.

you can imagine it like this:

```
trigger(onClickArgs); // that's why typescript indicates that there is no match to the function call.
```

To solve it you need to use the inline syntax:

```
onClick={() => trigger()}
```

In that way you are ignoring onClick supplied args and use the trigger without adding any parameters